# Oracle xQuery merge two xml matching nodes

Tags: xml, oracle, xquery, oracle12c

I have Oracle12 and two XML and want to merge them into one preferably using `xQuery`.

If 2nd XML have new nodes then they must be added.

In addition, if possible, if the node matches then change its value.

If this cannot be done with a XML of any kind, let's limit to comparing the contents of only the top-level nodes.

Something like

```
with t as (select
XMLType(
'<root>
  <node1>
   <data1>1</data1>
  </node1>
  <node2>
   <data2>2</data2>
  </node2>
  <node3>
   <data3>3</data3>
  </node3>
 </root>) oldx,
XMLType(
'<root>
  <node1>
   <data1>11</data1>
   <data12>12</data2>
  </node1>
  <node3>
   <data33>33</data33>
   <data34>34</data34>
  </node3>
 </root>) newx from dual)
select oldx, newx
--,xmlquery('copy $t := $x1 modify (for $i in $t when matched replace value of node $i with $x2 when not matched return insert node $x2 into $i) return $t' passing oldx as "x1", newx as "x2" returning content)
from t
```

the result must be

```
<root>
  <node1>
   <data1>11</data1>
   <data12>12</data2>
  </node1>
  <node2>
   <data2>2</data2>
  </node2>
  <node3>
   <data3>3</data3>
   <data33>33</data33>
   <data34>34</data34>
  </node3>
 </root>
```